# Calculate return date from loan date

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, date

I am trying to implement a library management database and I want to infer a return date based on the loan date, with `loandays`, which will hold number of days we allow user to have the book. This is my code so far:

```
CREATE TABLE LOAN 
( 
    COPY_ID int CONSTRAINT LOAN_COPY_FK 
            FOREIGN KEY(COPY_ID) REFERENCES COPY(COPY_ID) NOT NULL, 
    BORROWER_ID int CONSTRAINT LOAN_BORROWER_FK 
            FOREIGN KEY (BORROWER_ID) REFERENCES BORROWER (BORROWER_ID) NOT NULL, 
    LOAN_DATE DATE NOT NULL CONSTRAINT check_loan_date 
            CHECK (LOAN_DATE < RETURN_DATE),
    LOAN_DAYS int NOT NULL, 
    RETURN_DATE AS (LOAN_DATE + LOAN_DAYS) CONSTRAINT LOAN_PK 
            PRIMARY KEY(COPY_ID, BORROWER_ID) 
)
```

I have an error because `LOAN_DAYS` is integer and I don't know how to make it a day not a date with no month and year.

Comment: What error do you get?
Please add more information.
See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask for how to write a question. And please search for your problem online before asking.

Comment: Please, [do not use all caps](http://netiquette.wikia.com/wiki/Rule_number_2_-_Do_not_use_all_caps), except for your SQL code of course. It also makes stuff a lot harder to read.

Comment: please explain your problem in clear sentence then we all will help you

Comment: sorry, its my first time to ask here, I am getting the flowing error  {Msg 206, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Operand type clash: date is incompatible with int}

Comment: To make your question clearer, you can add the exact error message to your question. Edit the question by clicking the _edit_ button just below the tags :-)

Answer (score 1):

You should calculate `RETURN_DATE AS DATEADD(day, LOAN_DAYS, LOAN_DATE)`, and you cannot use the calculated `RETURN_DATE` in the check constraint `CONSTRAINT check_loan_date CHECK (LOAN_DATE < RETURN_DATE)`.

Instead I suggest have a check constraint that `LOAD_DAYS` is more than 0, which guarantees that `RETURN_DATE` is bigger than `LOAD_DATE`, as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE LOAN 
( 
    COPY_ID int CONSTRAINT LOAN_COPY_FK FOREIGN KEY(COPY_ID) REFERENCES COPY(COPY_ID) NOT NULL, 
    BORROWER_ID int CONSTRAINT LOAN_BORROWER_FK FOREIGN KEY (BORROWER_ID) REFERENCES BORROWER (BORROWER_ID) NOT NULL, 
    LOAN_DATE DATE NOT NULL ,
    LOAN_DAYS int NOT NULL CONSTRAINT check_loan_days CHECK (LOAN_DAYS > 0), 
    RETURN_DATE AS DATEADD(day,LOAN_DAYS,LOAN_DATE) CONSTRAINT LOAN_PK PRIMARY KEY(COPY_ID, BORROWER_ID) 
)
```

Comment: thank you @MKYuones  you saved me, thank a lot, my problems where 1. I used a check constraint in RETURN_DATE,  and I was calculating wrongly the the RETURN_DATE. thanks alot